# Is there a good field validation available in java 8+ which could replace guava PreConditions?

Tags: java, validation, java-8

I want to add field validations in a method in my application (e.g. field is not null and positive).

```
private void assertionTest(Integer i) {
    // want to first assert here that i is not null and positive 
    // something like: 
    // Preconditions.checkArgument( i != null && i > 0, "i should be non null positive number!" );
    // 
    System.out.println( "i: " + i);
}
```

Java 8 introduces Objects class which has some basic utility methods for null check validation:

```
public static <T> T requireNonNull(T obj)
public static <T> T requireNonNull(T obj, String message)
```

But it still lacks exhaustive list of validations which guava's Preconditions class provides, like the below:

```
checkArgument(boolean) throws IllegalArgumentException
checkState(boolean) throws IllegalStateException
etc.
```

Is there any some better alternative in Java 8+ for field validation so that I don't have to include external libraries like guava for that?

Comment: Just a note: Guava is almost 3MB of compressed bytecode. Don't include Guava just to save you writing these few one-line methods

Comment: The answer to your question is: No, there isn't.

Comment: It does not, but considering how many other goodies guava has....

Comment: Since Java 9, there’s also the family of `Objects.checkIndex(…)` methods. But there won’t be an “exhaustive list of validations”. Since there’s an infinite number of possible conditions, there is no point in even trying to cover all of them.

Comment: @saurabh.in is your question resolved?

Comment: @nazar_art yes, I think I have all the answeres I was looking for as part of this.

Answer (score 9):

***Java 8+*** (till 12) doesn't have such an approach (maybe in the future some changes will appear).

- From pure Java side, you can use [assert](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/assert):

  ```
   assert <condition> : <message>
  ```

In case of assertion fails `AssertionError` is thrown with `<message>`.

However, you should be sure that is activated by adding `-ea` attribute to **JVM**.
Asserts add more meaningful information to failed cases.
However, the aim of asserts isn't for checking method parameters. Thus, have a look at the second approach.

- As an alternative, you can use `apache-commons-lang` [Validate](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html) class:

  ```
   Validate.notNull(i, "this parameter can't be null")
   Validate.isTrue(i > 0, "The value must be greater than zero: %d", i);
  ```

This approach is much more preferable for validating parameters for the method.

---

If you are using Spring framework you could use [Assert](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/Assert.html) class.

Snipept From documentattion - Assertion utility class that assists in validating arguments.

Usage looks like:

```
Assert.notNull(clazz, "The class must not be null");
Assert.isTrue(i > 0, "The value must be greater than zero");
```

Comment: thanks nazar_art. Java assert keyword fits the bill for my usecase. In my tests, it throws AssertionError with my custom message when the assertion fails.

Comment: @nazar_art just remember that someone can disable asserts, of course

Comment: `assert` should be used to check invariants, *not* incoming parameter values.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) for this. They have a lot of validation methods in [Validate class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html). I'm not sure if it's expressive enough, but if you need anything else it's OK to just write it for yourself, there shouldn't be much code for simple checks.

Additionally, if you ever want to integrate these checks into your main business logic code (not just unit tests), you should take a look at [Bean Validation](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/). This way you are definitely not reinventing a wheel and your tests will only have to expect exception from validation framework.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution IMO is to just use

```
if (! test) { throws new Illegal[Argument|State]Exception (message + badparameteror) }
```

Even the authors of Guava have mixed feelings about using their validation methods particularly if performance is a concern.

If you find yourself doing this a lot for a particular class you can just make a helper method but I urge you not to require a whole library for trivial validation.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer methods for validation, why don't you write them yourself? Many people do. It's simple, fast and doesen't require any external dependencies.

Keep in mind that most of these methods are merely simple if conditions with an expressive name!

And then there is JSR 380 a.k.a "Bean Validation". It allows you to define validation constraints using annotations:

```
void assertionTest (@NotNull @PositiveOrZero Integer i) { ... }
```

BV has several benefits for larger applications:

- Less clutter, you can define constraints at a single place
- Many useful predefined constraints
- Custom annotations
- Localized error messages (that can be customized easily)
- Validation for complex objects and object graphs with performance in mind
- Context aware validation
- integration with other libs and frameworks
- and much more

Have a look at the [reference implementationn's documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/)

Answer (score 0):

I use spring validations, but sometimes I write the validations by extends the spring validations to control some custom behavior

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use `java.util.Optional` to validate with custom `Exception`or `RuntimeException` class

```
Optional.ofNullable(someVariables)
          .orElseThrow(
              () ->
                  new CustomException("Some message"));
```